# SmartSVN and SVN Version Confusion

Tags: svn, smartsvn

I am running SmartSVN version 6.6.11 and am getting a message saying that the project I am trying to access is part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater working copy.   It is asking me to upgrade but I am already running the SVN 1.7 client!

I am at a loss.   Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

SmartSVN does not use an external SVN client. *SmartSVN 6.6* supports the *SVN 1.6* working copy format. *SmartSVN 7* supports the *SVN 1.7* working copy format. At the time of writing, a release candidate of *SmartSVN 7* is available:

https://www.smartsvn.com/download/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I downloaded the release candidate and am getting the following message after setting it up and importing:  No repository found in 'svn://localhost'?  I seem to have stuck myself between a rock and a hard place as I don't know how to downgrade my repository from 1.7 to 1.6 to keep using the older SmartSVN!

Comment: Did you contact the syntevo support?

Comment: Never mind the above.   I am not completely sure how I sorted myself out...but...I am fixed.   BTW, I had contacted support a couple times yesterday and was trying to avoid another contact today!  Cheers, Will